# Laravel 5.7 validation works still not

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I have already asked question about Laravel 5.7 validation, however it still does not work quite right. the validation is not executed at all when sending the content.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
    
        $data=$request->all();
$validator = Validator::make($data, [
            'first_name' => 'alpha|min:2|max:30',
        ]);
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where are your validation rules?

Comment: You already have a `Player $player`, no need to `Player::where('id', $player->id)`

Comment: are you asking about Authentication? does not seem like you are asking about validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if your are not using form validation then maybe it will be helpful for you.
> I add validator example in your code, you can try it
> maybe your problem will resolve

```
public function update(Request $request, Player $player)
{ 
//example validation   
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'id' => 'required|integer', //put your fields
            'text' => 'required|string' //put your fields
            ]);
        if ($validator->fails()){
            return "Invalid Data";
        }
if(Auth::check()){
                   
        $playerUpdate = Player::where('id', $player->id)
                            ->update([
                                   'first_name' => $request->input('fist_name'),
                                   'last_name' => $request->input('last_name')
                            ]);

        if($playerUpdate){
            return redirect()->route('players.show', ['player'=> $player->id])
            ->with('success' , 'player foo');
        }
        

    }
     
    return back()->withInput()->with('errors', 'Foo error');
    
    
    
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see your validation code at all.
there are two ways for implementing the validation in laravel

1. Form Request Validation
2. validation in controller methods

Please Add one, and try again

Comment: Hello, I added now the validation.